# How to permanently change z-index number of the toggle menu page (WordPress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, toggle, z-index

I need to changed z-index number in a toggle menu page.
I added the following code.
`jQuery('.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown').attr("style","z-index:500;");`
It changes an existing z-index number, but when I click a toggle menu, the number came back to the existing number (999999).
Would you plese let me know how to permanently change the number?
Before adding jQuery:
[image]

After adding jQuery:
[image]

After clicking a toogle menu:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What's a "toggle page"? Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We don't work with images of code around here. :)

Comment: It sounds like the menu library sets the z-index value. You'll have to figure out what that is.

Comment: @isherwood: thank you for your comments and advice, and I added jQuery. Would you please let me know how to change Menu library?